# Problems headless chromedriver downloads

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an automation process created with java selenium-webdriver, chromedriver and work with eclipse. The point is that by doing the process with headless and disable gpu I get that the download is correct but it does not appear in the directory and instead if the headless option and gpu if it appears in the directory. Attached the code below and if there is someone who knows how to do it and can help me, I will be grateful, thanks.

> //*********PARA CHROME*******
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\driver\chromedriver235\chromedriver.exe");//localiz
>   version 2.35 chromedriver

```
String downloadFilepath = "C:\\Users\\Dani\\Desktop\\FACTURAS";
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);//ventanas emergentes
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);//directorio para descargas local
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");//necesario para el headless (tamaño pantalla)
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");//desactivar notificaciones
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");//evitar que apareguin infobars
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);// Bydefault it will accepts all popups.
        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//indicamos segundos entre acciones
```

Comment: Where did you `Attached the code below`?

Comment: I attached now sorry thanks ;)

Comment: DebanjanB have you any idea?

Comment: downloading files in headless mode is disabled by chromedriver for security reasons